# In 'it was a lot of fun', is 'fun a noun or an adjective?

Tags: vocabulary, modifiers

> [i] I hope that you have **a lot of fun** at the flower festival.
>   [ii] I don't think I'll go again, but it was **a lot of fun**!  ([daum.net](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=a%20lot%20of%20fun&dic=eng))

At first, I took it granted that ***a lot of fun***’s both in [i] an [ii] have the same structure. But when this idea struck me that *a lot of fun* in [ii] seems to be adjective, I flipped over grammar books, looking for which says *a lot of* is a modifier for adjectives. But I have not found.
So I started to think [ii] has this structure and meaning:
‘it was **a lot** [= very] **of fun** [= fun]’
Can I get exact meaning of [ii]?

Comment: In one dictionary, under the noun "fun", it has this example: ***she's full of fun.***

Comment: In these examples, *fun* is a noun.  *A lot of fun* is a noun phrase.  What makes it seem like an adjective to you?

Comment: @snailplane: maybe because in the sentence "I am good", _good_ is an adjective, and not the _noun_ (which would mean something completely different). I would say you can see the sentence _It was fun_ as [subject][copula][adjective].

Comment: @oerkelens Sure.  For younger AmE speakers like myself, *fun* has become a regular adjective.  But it's still a noun a lot of the time, like in the OP's examples.

Comment: @snailplane Now I got an idea why I was thinking ‘fun’ as adjective in the case. It’s from my own language that has no post-modifiers as in “[A](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/fun) something that is amusing”. When I interpret ‘fun’ into my language, [A]’s sequence changes: amusing something. After this thought, I read ‘a lot of fun’ as ‘fantastic/amusing thing’, and this made me read ‘a lot of’ as a quantifier before the noun.

Comment: It might help to compare the two senses of *fun* with *joy*: "It was a great joy," and "It was so joyful."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of "of" here excludes the possibility of having an adjective following the expression.  "A lot of" is used as a determiner referring to a quantity of something and a determiner does not modify an adjective directly.

It would be the same with words like *some* or *any*:

> It was really some fun.
>   It wasn't any fun.
>   It was no fun at all.

"A lot" (without "of") could be used to express intensity in front of an adjective in comparisons :

> He's a lot taller than his brother.

It is possible to use the word "fun" as an adjective instead of "funny" in sentences like:

> He's fun to be with.
>   The party was fun.

Anything said about "a lot of"  would stand for "a good deal of" as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you rephrase it (don't actually use it that way) as 'big amount of the thing called "fun"', emphasis on "thing", it should become clear that it is a noun, no?